# Auth0 TouchID Missing Public Key

Tags: ios, auth0, touch-id

I am building a universal iOS app using Auth0 TouchID for authentication. A0TouchIDLockViewController runs as expected except on an iPhone 5S. In this case login fails, reporting

```
There was an error logging in
```

The console shows the error

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed
"there is not an associated public key for specified client_id/user_id/device".
```

Does anyone know how to correct this error?

Comment: I was thinking this is a version issue but it does say here you can use it with 5s, NOTE: You can use Touch ID with an iPhone 5s or later, an iPad Air 2, or an iPad mini 3 or later. https://auth0.com/docs/connections/passwordless/ios-touch-id-swift

Comment: The error by itself indicates that Auth0 does not have a matching public key for the provided combination of `client_id`, `user_id` and `device`. According to the docs, the public key should have been associated by Lock upon the first time the user login; any error during the key association could then lead to that outcome. You might be better contacting Auth0 support directly as troubleshooting this will require internal access to the specific account.